# Regex: Extract everything following 2 characters, or the beginning

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract subdomains+domains from some loosely formatted URLs. Some start with http:// and other do not. I covered the http:// case with the following regex:

```
(?<=(\/\/))[^\/]*
```

which matches something like

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

to

```
stackoverflow.com
```

which is correct. However now I want it to match the above case AND

```
stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

to

```
stackoverflow.com
```

I'm using some third party tool which doesn't clearly state what they are using for regex parsing. How can this expression be done?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew doesn't seem to be a valid regex unfortunately. I tried escparing the slashes and it still doesn't work, matches "https:" in the first case

Comment: If tool is python based then better to use: `(?:(?<=://)|(?<=^))[^/:]+(?!.*://)` otherwise use: `(?<=://|^)[^/:]+(?!.*://)`

Comment: @anubhava that seems to have worked, thanks! Just had to escape the slashes. If you post that as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If tool is python based then you may use this regex:

```
(?:(?<=://)|^)[^/:]+(?!.*://)
```

Negative lookahead `(?!.*://)` will prevent matching a string that has `://` ahead thus avoiding matching `https` at the start.

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/GP80ve/3)

otherwise use:

```
(?<=:\/\/|^)[^\/:]+(?!.*:\/\/)
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/GP80ve/2)